# AP que adiciona como nova resposta um complemento para a própria pergunta

Tags: debate

Exemplo:
[deixar / no final da url](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73331/deixar-no-final-da-url)

Nesses, como devemos proceder?
Copiar e colar a resposta dentro da pergunta e remover a resposta do AP?

Acho que o AP pensa que isso aqui é um forum.

Comment: Editar a resposta, coloca-la na pergunta. Dizer ao utilizador para fazer isso sempre que precise de dar mais detalhes. Sinalizar a resposta.

Comment: Neste caso especifico eu eliminaria o primeiro passo.

Answer (score 9):

Neste tipo de perguntas, a meu ver, devemos fazer assim:

1. Editar a resposta e coloca-la na pergunta.
2. Informar ao utilizador para fazer isso sempre que precise de dar mais detalhes.
3. Sinalizar a resposta como "**não é uma resposta.** Esta resposta não é uma tentativa concreta de resolver o problema. Seria melhor transformada em comentário, edição, outra pergunta ou excluída.

Neste caso especifico eu eliminaria o primeiro passo porque está meio confuso o que interessa da pergunta e dos detalhes que ele deixou, que na verdade é só outra forma de explicar.

Comment: Verdade, não reparei que se trata de uma mesma explicação com palavras diferentes. Obrigado pelas instruções!